# Reload a page when JS console error is seen

Tags: javascript

I see a set of browser error messages on first time loading of a screen. On reloading the page the messages disappear. Is there a way to reload a page when we see JS errors on the console.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check the errors, and get rid of them in the first place?

Comment: It would probably be best to debug the errors instead of hiding them

Comment: Or try to catch those errors with a try { ... } catch block.

Answer (score 2):

You should stop, and think of what you're doing. It's a bad idea. you should be asking how to fix the errors, and not how to silence them.

Also, constantly refreshing the client because of errors is bad UX.

But, hypothetically speaking, this can be done by overriding the console.error method and invoking a browser refresh instead.

like so:

### WARNING ---- STUPID CODE AHEAD ---- WARNING

```
console.error = function(){
   window.location.reload()
}
```